# Subdirectory in R package

Tags: r

I am creating a R package, and would like to organize my R subdirectory, with subdirectories. Since only the function defined in R files at the root directory are exported, I added this code to one file at the root:

```
sourceDir <- function(path, trace = TRUE, ...) {
  for (nm in list.files(path, pattern = "\\.[RrSsQq]$")) {
    print(nm)
    if(trace) cat(nm,":")           
    source(file.path(path, nm), ...)
    if(trace) cat("\n")
  }
}

sourceDir("R/DataGenerator")
```

When I use "CRTL+SHIFT+B" on RStudio, I see that the nm files are sourced. But once the package is loaded, none of the functions defined in the subdirectory R/DataGenerator are accessible, neither using :: nor using ::: .

How can I export functions defined in subdirectories of R ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: The lack of proper support for nested package hierarchy was one of the reasons that prompted me to write **‹[modules](https://github.com/klmr/modules)›**, which implements a superior, Python-like  package/module system for R. You may want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Collate: field in the DESCRIPTION file to specify paths to files to be included

```
Collate: foo.R bar/baz.R
```

A helper to generate the collate line might be something like

```
fls = paste(dir(pattern="R", recursive=TRUE), collapse=" ")
cat(strwrap(sprintf("Collate: %s", fls), exdent=4), sep="\n")
```

Comment: That is one elegant piece of code — just beware that your `pattern` is too broad, it will capture non-R source files (and it’s case sensitive so it will miss all source files that don’t use a capital-`R` extension). It should be `'\\.[rR]$'`.

Comment: Can you please show us an example R package where this worked? When I try to follow your approach I get the error `Error in .install_package_code_files(".", instdir) : 
files in 'Collate' field missing from '/home/user/packagename/R': subdir/code.R ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package packagename`

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that I can help; it seems like the kind of thing that I wouldn't have just made up or thought that I knew, but you're right that with current R this definitely does not work. The parallel package and documentation suggest that this works only for OS-specific (`windows`, `unix`)  subdirectories...

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the discussion in the comments to the accepted answer between Martin Morgan and me, this does not seem to work in current R versions. My workaround to get a bit better file organisation is to prefix the filenames using what would have been the subdirectories names.