# roxygen2 not creating .Rd documentation

Tags: r, rstudio, roxygen2

I am unable to generate .Rd documentation files for my package using RStudio and Roxygen2. First, let me mention that I have gone through similar problems posted here and have already done the following:

1. Roxygen2 blocks initiated at the beginning of file with a #'
2. Configured Build Tools>Checked generate documentation with Roxygen> Configure > Checked all fields under 'Use roxygen to generate' and 'Automatically roxygenize when running'
3. Made sure there were no .Rd files in the 'man' folder

And even after that, when I perform a 'Build and Reload' on RStudio I get the following output (please note the line that reads: No man pages found in package  MYPACKAGE:

> =
>   => devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))
>   >
>
> > Updating MYPACKAGE documentation
> >     Loading  MYPACKAGE
> >     Documentation completed
> >
> > ==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source MYPACKAGE
> >
> > - installing to library C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.3
> > - installing *source* package 'MYPACKAGE' ...
> >       ** R
> >       ** data
> >       *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
> >       ** preparing package for lazy loading
> >       No man pages found in package  'MYPACKAGE' 
> >       ** help
> >       *** installing help indices
> >       ** building package indices
> >       ** testing if installed package can be loaded
> > - DONE (MYPACKAGE)

**Edit:**
Upon further investigation, it appears that this was caused by the fact that I have sub-directories within my R directory, which is not supported by default. A possible solution was located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776643/subdirectory-in-r-package) which, however, I haven't yet tried out. I will report back with the outcome as soon as I am able to perform the tests.

Comment: RStudio settings Tools => Projects => Build-Tools: Generate documentatio... is set?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. roxygen2 was creating correctly the md files in the /man directory but they were not found at compilation time.  I had the following error.

```
No man pages found in package
```

After a bit of time I found that in one of the R file I had a source statement

```
source("C:/Users/vaulot/Google Drive/Scripts/R library/dv_function_pr2.R")
```

My guess is that there was some code in the source file interfering with roxygen2.